# autoSizeTextType property for wear LayoutElementBuilders.Text

Tags: android, wear-os, android-textview-autosize, android-wear-3.0, wear-tile

In Android wear [TileService](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/tiles/TileService) we have to use [`LayoutElementBuilders.Text`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/tiles/LayoutElementBuilders.Text) for displaying Text. In xml we can use [`autoSizeTextType`](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/autosizing-textview) for TextView.

How can i apply this property in `LayoutElementBuilders.Text` for wear `TileService` ?

I didn't find any method in the Builder.

Comment: It's not a supported feature and the rendering of tiles is distinct from Views.

Comment: @YuriSchimke any plan to support this feature ?

Comment: I am not a developer of the Tiles project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am sharing my solution to solve my problem.

Requirement was not to change font size when user change display font size from setting.

For fixed size i have to use font size in `dp` in `dimen` file like `20dp`.

In [`DimensionBuilders.SpProp.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/protolayout/DimensionBuilders.SpProp.Builder) class method `setValue` expect value in `sp`.

In [`LayoutElementBuilders.FontStyle.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/tiles/LayoutElementBuilders.FontStyle.Builder) class method `setSize` expect `SpProp`.

So i have to calculate a scale factor and multiply with dp value.

```
    fun getScaleFactorForDp(context: Context) : Float {
        return (1.0f/context.resources.configuration.fontScale)
    }


    fun getSpProp(context: Context, @DimenRes dimensionId: Int, scaleFactor : Float = 1f): DimensionBuilders.SpProp {
        val spValue = (context.resources.getDimension(dimensionId) / context.resources.displayMetrics.density) * scaleFactor
        return DimensionBuilders.SpProp.Builder()
            .setValue(spValue)
            .build()
    }

   -------------------------------------------------     
    
    val scaleFactor = getScaleFactorForDp(context)
    LayoutElementBuilders.FontStyle.Builder()
        .setSize(getSpProp(context, R.dimen.text_size,scaleFactor))
        ....
        build()
```